# Calculator can't handle 2.0 - 2.0

Tags: python

I wanted to build a calculator in python, but for some reason the calculator cannot handle 2.0 - 2.0

Expected results: 0.0

Actual results: The Operator is invalid. Please try again.

I've tried to test this with other numbers, but they all work. I can't seem to find much on the internet.
Heres the code.

```
print("Whats your first number?")
num1 = float(input())
print("Whats your second number?")
num2 = float(input())
print("""Whats your operator?
1. Multiplication
2. Addition
3. Division
4. Subtraction





""")
operator = int(input())
operations = [1 , 2, 3, 4]
solution = 0


for x in operations:
    if x == operator:
        if operator == 1:
            solution = num1 * num2
        elif operator == 2:
            solution = num1 + num2
        elif operator == 3:
            solution = num1 / num2
        elif operator == 4:
            solution = num1 - num2
        else:
           solution = False


if solution == False:
    print("The operator is invalid. Please, try again.")
else:
    print(solution)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see this problem for *all* operations that result in zero. Why? See what you get when you do

```
print( 0 == False )
```

This outputs

```
True
```

Instead of using a boolean value to indicate an invalid operation, I suggest you use `None`.

Change `else: solution = False` to `else: solution = None`

`None` is not equal to anything else in python, so you can change your condition to:

```
if solution is None: 
    print("Invalid operation")
else:
    print(solution)
```

Comment: Replacing `solution = 0` with `solution = True` at the head of the loop would be much simpler.

Comment: I actually didn't know None existed. Anyway, the code now works as intended. Thank you.

Comment: @KenY-N That wouldn't work. In this case, `solution = num1 - num2` was executed and its result happened to be zero. The `if` is triggered because `0 == False` is `True`.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Oops, my misreading - I missed that `solution` had a double use there.